# foreach implementation crashes and generates error in R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I am new to using `foreach` package in R and need some tips on some of the aspects regarding
my code.

I have a dataframe that has `location.Id` and an `iterationID` as shown below

```
exp_df <- data.frame(location.Id = sample(1:10, 1000, replace = T),
                      iterationID = 1:1000)
```

For each unique `location.Id` in `exp_df`, I have variables `x1`, `x2`, `x3` etc and this is
saved as a csv file in my directory

```
dat <- data.frame(location.Id = 1:10,
                  x1 = rnorm(10),
                  x2 = rnorm(10),
                  x3 = rnorm(10))

data.table::fwrite(dat, 'dat.csv')
```

My goal is for each row of `exp_df`, I want to select what `location.Id` it is and then do
some computation using `x1`, `x2` and `x3` as follows

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

myClusters <- makeCluster(6)  
registerDoParallel(myClusters)

results <- 
foreach(i = 1:nrow(exp_df)) %dopar% 
  
{
 
  library(data.table) 
  library(dplyr)
  
  temp <- exp_df[i, ]
 
  mydat <- fread('dat.csv')[location.Id == temp$location.Id] 

  mydat <- mydat %>% dplyr::mutate(finalVal = x1 + x2 + x3)
  
  return(mydat)
}

stopCluster(myClusters)
```

My actual computation for `location_Id` is more complex and reads in more individual csv files like `dat` so above is an simplification of my problem. Also for some reason, I cannot preread `dat` outside the foreach loop and have to read in inside the foreach loop

My question is since inside the foreach loop, I am reading a file called `dat.csv` does it create any conflict if by chance the individual cores are trying to read in `dat` at the same time?

When I implement the above code for my actual code, R starts crashing down and gives the following error

```
Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection
```

What are the reasons the above error is generated?

Thank you

Comment: Is it a memory issue?

Comment: I don't know that is why I was asking. what leads to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something which seemed to work and wondered if anyone has an opinion on it.

I split my `exp_df` into small chunks

```
splitdf <- split(exp_df, (as.numeric(rownames(exp_df))-1) %/% 50)
```

and then ran the above code for each chunks and then merged my results later on

```
final_result <- list()
for(l in 1:length(splitdf)) {

    exp_df <- splitdf[[l]]

    myClusters <- makeCluster(6)  
    registerDoParallel(myClusters)

    results <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(exp_df)) %dopar% 

    {

      library(data.table) 
      library(dplyr)

      temp <- exp_df[i, ]

      mydat <- fread('dat.csv')[location.Id == temp$location.Id] 

      mydat <- mydat %>% dplyr::mutate(finalVal = x1 + x2 + x3)

     return(mydat)
  }

stopCluster(myClusters)

final_result[[l]]  <- rbindlist(result)
}
```